# How to use default value in LOAD statement in DB2?

Tags: insert, load, db2

I am currently using DB2 . I do not know much about load statement.
I am using this query to load data..

> LOAD FROM "IXAC.CSV" OF DEL METHOD P ('IX',1,2,3,4,) MESSAGES
>   "SYAC.MSG"  INSERT INTO SYNC.AC_COUNT (       "TYPE",         AC1,        AC2,        AC3,
>         AC4  ) ; COMMIT;

In "IXAC.CSV" there are 4 int values separated with comma. My problem is that how can i insert 'IX' with load statement as a constant with each row insert.

I tried this but not found any success. I am newer in database.

Help me .. 
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table definition in the database to have a default value for the column 'IX' (it looks like you want "TYPE"?).

Then do the load as normal, leaving out the IX column.

Comment: I have done this for a table and i have more than 20 tables to do same task and it require change in table structure . is there any other way?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I tried completely ignoring the column and leaving it blank but with its respective comma in the csv. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to edit the .csv file a workaround is that you can use a text editor (such as ultra edit) that supports wildcards or regular expressions in its find/replace feature and replace each carriage return/line feed with a CR/LF followed by "IX," (quotes optional depending on if you want to specify a text delimiter on insert). then your .csv file will have all your data.